# localStorage access from firefox extension scope

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon

I have a Selenium program running Chrome/Firefox web drivers with my extension on each browser. The extension is generic and each time the program runs it loads different config to the extension using localStorage.

**The flow is:**

Start the web driver with the extension installed.

Navigate to a web page with the extension's scope: in Chrome - chrome:chrome-extension://eebpfcjkplahlajlfagjnopfnhjngnje/startup.png in Firefox - moz-extension://870f3a82-b6d0-7c40-a261-a9ae20fabc7d/manifest.json

Run js code:

```
localStorage.setItem('blocks', JSON.stringify({urls:['https://*/*css*','http://*/*css*','https://*/*png*','http://*/*png*']}));
```

Then, the extension is syncing with the new added values to localStorage and do stuff.

Everything is working great in Chrome. In Firefox, I can't run the js code at the extension's scope page, I get the following error:

```
SecurityError: The operation is insecure.
```

I know the FF changed their entire API's for extensions in the last version and I wonder what is the right way to achieve my goal.

In general I'm looking for a way to share data between the selenium web driver and the extension.

Comment: This is a bug in FF. It applies its website policies to extension's DOM. You can add an exclusion for the extension URL in Firefox options for cookies.

Comment: @wOxxOm thanks. how do I do that?

Comment: I only know how to [add exceptions manually in Firefox options](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/websites-say-cookies-are-blocked-unblock-them#w_check-cookie-settings).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution for this was to upgrade Firefox version to 61.0.2
In latest versions extension API is same as in Chrome and working as expected.